# WPF MVVM ComboBox with default selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have this trivial question, but nothing works for me:/ 
I'm trying to set default selected combobox value from viewmodel. Here's the code:

```
public class ItemFilter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In ViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    SelectedItemFilter = ItemFilters[0];
}

public IList<ItemFilter> ItemFilters
{
    get
    {
        IList<ItemFilter> itemFilter = new List<ItemFilter>();
        itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 0, Name = "All" });
        itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 1, Name = "One" });
        itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" });
        return itemFilter;
    }
}

public ItemFilter SelectedItemFilter
{
    get { return _selectedItemFilter; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItemFilter, value); }
}
```

In View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridItems"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Foo" Binding="{Binding Path=SizeComment}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="120">
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ItemFilters, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItemFilter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first obvious reason is that `ItemFilters` is created on every request. So `SelectedItemFilter = ItemFilters[0];` creates a list of filters and then assign the first one to `SelectedItemFilter`. When ComboBox requests list of filters it gets a **different** list of filters. So `SelectedItemFilter` cannot be found in `ComboBox` items list. There are two solutions:

1. A better one -> instatiate ItemFilters once in a constructor.
2. If 1. is not applicable then override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in `ItemFilter` class

Answer (score 1):

As @Zbigniew suggests creating a new List in the getter of a property is a bad idea.

The constructor of your `MainViewModel` will create one `List<ItemFilter>` and set the `SelectedItemFilter` to the first `ItemFilter` object in this one and then there will be another `List<ItemFilter>` created when the binding in the view is resolved and the `SelectedItemFilter` instance won't be in this new list. That's why you don't get any item selected in the `ComboBox`.

You should create the source collection *once*:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    IList<ItemFilter> itemFilter = new List<ItemFilter>();
    itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 0, Name = "All" });
    itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 1, Name = "One" });
    itemFilter.Add(new ItemFilter() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" });
    ItemFilters = itemFilter;

    SelectedItemFilter = itemFilter[0];
}

public IList<ItemFilter> ItemFilters { get; }

public ItemFilter SelectedItemFilter
{
    get { return _selectedItemFilter; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _selectedItemFilter, value); }
}
```